# Start Session & End Session In Moving Average

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I Want To Calculate and Plot Simple Moving Average Based On Start Session Time And End Session Time

ma=ta.sma(close,100)

issession=time(timeframe.period,"0900-1650:1234567")
time_Condition= not na(issession)

plot(time_Condition and ma ? 1 : 0 , color.black, linewidth=2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a transparent color for the plot to hide a moving average that is outside a defined session:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
ma = ta.sma(close,100)

issession = time(timeframe.period,"0901-1650:1234567") 
time_Condition = not na(issession)

plot(ma, color = time_Condition? color.red : color(na), linewidth = 2)
```

[image]